# extracting data from encoded tag in xml

Tags: javascript, xml, titanium, extract, encode

I am working on a feed and wa trying to parse the following tag:

```
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<p><strong><a href="http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/sf.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-54126" alt="sf" src="http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/sf.jpg" width="210" height="240" /></a>A SF Cllr in Strabane has denied allegations that they assaulted a member of the SDLP party.</strong></p> <p>On Sunday the PSNI confirmed they were investigating an incident after they received a report of an assault in the early hours of Saturday morning.</p> <p>The Sinn Fein Cllr, who cannot be named for legal reasons, said that they totally deny the allegations that have been reported to the PSNI by the SDLP.</p> <p>The Cllr also said that they are seeking legal advice in relation to what they called &#8220;highly prejudicial&#8221; comments made by SDLP members on social media websites and to the local media.</p> <p>Sinn Fein says the allegations made have been presented as fact by the SDLP, which has attempted to subvert the Cllrs right to due legal process.</p> <p>And the statement concludes that the comments made by some SDLP members are unsubstaniated, and, as of yet un-investigated.</p> <p>Earlier this week the SDLP claimed that a representative in Strabane had been assaulted by a Sinn Fein Cllr over the weekend.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p>
]]>
</content:encoded>
```

I only have a basic bit of knowledge on the subject and was trying:

```
for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
        data.push({
            title: items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text,
            content: item(i).getElementsByTagName("content: encoded").item(0).text,
            className: "TableRow", 
            hasChild: true, 
            js:"external.js", 

        });
```

It's the content tag that's throwing an error.Can anyone help me with how to decode this? I am working with titanium but it is basically just javascript. I need the image and description

Comment: This question is off-topic because they will only allow us to close typo/syntax related questions as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is space in ("content: encoded") so remove it and try again.

Comment: if you find this post helps you then you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: done. If you are free you may be able to help with this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616087/regular-expression-search-with-xml