# regular expression search with xml

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, escaping, titanium

I'm working on parsing an xml feed and ii have the following tag

```
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<p><a href="http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/An-Grianan-Hotel.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-54286" alt="An Grianan Hotel" src="http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/An-Grianan-Hotel.jpg" width="488" height="244" /></a></p> <p>Gardai are appealing for information about last an armed robbery at An Grianan Hotel in Burt in the earkly hours of this morning..</p> <p>Three men entered the premises at quarter to three, at least one was armed with a shotgun. They escaped with a sum of money.</p> <p>Local Superintendent Andy Archbold is leading the investigation, and has been outlining what happened&#8230;&#8230;&#8230;&#8230;..</p> <p><strong> </strong></p>
]]>
</content:encoded>
```

I need to be able to grab the image from this. I was wondering what is the best way to do this? could I search for a regular expression? Also with regard to the &#8230 etc. is there a way to easily convert these?
All help appreciated.
Below is my current code for getting the feed and looping through it, my goal is t set the leftImage element of my data array to be the image inside the content encoded tag.

```
var url="http://www.highlandradio.com/feed/"; 
//rss feed url
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.onload = function() {
    // Data is returned from the blog, start parsing
    var doc = this.responseXML.documentElement;

    // begin looping through blog posts
    var items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    console.log(items);
    for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
        data.push({                
            title: "'"+items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text+"'",
            leftImage:'NewsStory.png',
            dataToPass: "'"+items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).text+"'",    
            className: "TableRow", 
            hasChild: true, 
            jsTest: true,
            js:"external.js"
        });
}
};
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression is best way for pattern search. a regex like this maybe can help you :

```
<img\s.*?src=\"(.*?)\".*?/>
```

This regex extract the scr attribute value, in your example :
http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/An-Grianan-Hotel.jpg

Comment: @ boulatin this is giving me a syntax error. Can you see a small mistake?

Comment: @user2363025, this regex works on Expresso tool, if you use in java or C# program perhaps change to `<img\\s.*?src=\\\"(.*?)\\\".*?/>`